# FluentNHibernate. I need to map a hasmany relationship to a joined subclass entity type

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to get this FluentNHibernate mapping to work. I have three tables Person, Employee and Employer. The Employee table extends the attributes of the Person table, and it's primary key is a foreign key to the Person table.

The Employee table also has a foriegn key to the Employer table. An employer can have many employees, and each employee is a person.

I have used FluentNHibernate to map these three tables. I used a Joined Subclass mapping for Employee -> Person.

I am trying to get a mapping to work so that I can get employers and their associated employees (eager fetching), but the generated select statement selects the EmployerId on **both** the Employee table (good), and the Person table (bad) resulting in an error (see below).

SELECT **employees0_.EmployerId** as Employee5_2_, employees0_.
PersonId as PersonId2_, employees0_.PersonId as PersonId1_1_, employees0_.FirstN
ame as FirstName1_1_, employees0_.LastName as LastName1_1_, employees0_1_.PayRat
e as PayRate2_1_, **employees0_1_.EmployerId** as EmployerId2_1_, employer1_.Employe
rId as EmployerId0_0_, employer1_.Name as Name0_0_ FROM [Person] employees0_ lef
t outer join Employee employees0_1_ on employees0_.PersonId=employees0_1_.Employ
eeId left outer join [Employer] employer1_ on employees0_1_.EmployerId=employer1
*.EmployerId WHERE employees0*.Employee.EmployerId=@p0;@p0 = 1

Please find the schema, class and Fluent Mappings below. What have I done wrong?

I have defined classes for these tables as follows:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string PersonClassification { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Employer
{
    public int EmployerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public Employer Employer { get; set; }
    public decimal PayRate { get; set; }

}

public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.PersonId).Column("PersonId").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.FirstName);
        Map(x => x.LastName);
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("PersonClassification");
    }
}

public class EmployeeMap : SubclassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        this.DiscriminatorValue("Employee");

        Join
            (
                "Employee",
                join =>
                {
                    join.Optional();
                    join.KeyColumn("EmployeeId");
                    join.Map(x => x.PayRate);
                    join.References(x => x.Employer).Column("EmployerId");
                }
            );
    }
}

public class EmployerMap : ClassMap<Employer>
{
    public EmployerMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.EmployerId).Column("EmployerId").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasMany(x => x.Employees).KeyColumn("Employee.EmployerId");
    }
}
```

Comment: You may not care anymore now (8 months later), but could you also post the code that you use to execute your query - the query that generates the above SQL?  Thanks.